# Get an integer from a string in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a String like

```
#IntegerNumber Some Text
```

I want to get only `IntegerNumber` as `int` from the string in python3.
I tried this but it didn't worked:

```
search_key = str(issue_id)
search_string = str(toggl_data['description'])
search = re.search(search_key, search_string)
```

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with the regex if we know neither how the regex (`search_key`) nor how _exactly_ the string to search in (`search_string`) looks? Provide actual strings, not variables whose values can't know. Also, "did not work" how? Did not find the number? Returned wrong type? Threw exception?

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, remember to upvote and accept.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm dont know how You are calling all these things but try :

```
import re
search_key = str("#([0-9]+) \S+")
search_string = str(toggl_data['description'])
search_result = re.search(search_key, search_string).group(1)
```

and now Your var **search_result** will contain result

Answer (score 0):

You can try like that:

```
import re
search_string = str(toggl_data['description'])
result = int(re.search('(?<=^#)\w+', search_string).group())
```

This will work with assumption that `#IntegerNumber` is always at the beginning of `search_string` and there are only digits after `#`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, assuming that

1. The integer value is always at the start of the string
2. It is always preceded by a single "#" character
3. It is separated from the rest of the string by spaces.

   `integer_value = int(search_string.split(" ")[0][1:])`

It splits the text by spaces, takes the first word ("#45") ignores the first character, and converts the resulting string to an integer. Useful if you want to avoid regular expressions for some reason.